# Bf falcon trying to skid

Tags: engine, ford, brakes, noise, transmission

i tried doing a skid and burnout i put my foot all the way down on the brake and accelerator with traction control off tried multiple times nothing happen expect when i went to a dirt road it worked but it made these weird noises at the front and it was bogging down when full flat brake and accelerator at around 2k rpms wouldnt go any higher cause i was too scared more rpms the more it did that bog down thing.

now i was driving home and everytime i stopped and accelerated off id hear some clunks at the rear it is a automatic by the way and also i think my brakes or rotors are shot everytime i brake when going around 30+kmh i hear metal grinding together please help me!

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's not a good idea to put your personal email address in a post.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you damaged the rear end differential. One way to possibly diagonse this is to jack the back end up, putting it on jack stands. Once suspended, rotate one wheel while someone else keeps the other side still, with the transmission in neutral. If you're hearing any type of grinding noise or metal on metal, you've probably got an issue. At this point, you'd need to pull the differential cover (draining the fluid first, looking for metal pieces), and inspect the ring/pinion as well as the spider gears for anything looking out of place.